# How to check java version of a running java process used

Tags: spring-boot, jvm

I created a web project used spring boot and deployed it in remote server, and it's default JDK is

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_72
```

because I used java 8 in my project, so before starting my project, I explicitly exec below command

```
 export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65"
```

then start my project

```
./myapp.jar
```

but when I exec below command

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

I am a little confused, I'm not sure which jdk version my project actually used? 
That is there is a java process

```
jps -l
17429 /var/myapp.jar
```

How do I know which java version it is used?

Thanks @frant.hartm

```
# ps aux | grep 17429
root     17429  0.4  6.7 5995260 1104984 pts/13 Sl  19:16   0:29 /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -Dserver.port=8081 -jar /var/myapp.jar

# jcmd 17429 VM.version
17429:
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM version 25.65-b01
JDK 8.0_65
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jcmd:

```
jcmd process_id VM.version

$ jcmd 9619 VM.version
9619:
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM version 24.80-b11
JDK 7.0_80
```

Alternatively, you can use ps to find out which java binary was used:

```
ps aux | grep 9619
user  9619  0.0  0.5 4031224 82480 ?       Sl   12:31   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -cp /usr/lib/jvm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `which java`, it will give you which java binary is used by default on your OS.

If you want to run your application with Java 8 and leave default location unchanged just run:

```
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java ./myapp.jar
```

Comment: thanks but I want to know if eixst some jvm tool e.g. `jstack jmap` could help you to know the java version of a java process

Comment: On most linux distributions that have some kind of "alternatives" system (like Ubuntu) this will point to a symbolic link (e.g. /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java, /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java)